# Trouble to delete an uploaded image using Jquery Multiple file upload plugins

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

I'm using jquery multiple image upload plugin. here I was able to insert images into database. and I put a close icon beside every image preview. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
  var url = (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.com' ||
                window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,

    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>').append('<span class="close_img"><img src="/Moumita/image_upload/img/close_img.png"/><span>');

            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    })
 });
```

And in UploadHandler.php these function are also present :

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->options = array(


            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
            'user_dirs' => false,
            'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
            // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
            'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
            'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
                'OPTIONS',
                'HEAD',
                'GET',
                'POST',
                'PUT',
                'PATCH',
                'DELETE'
            ),
            ..........................


            )
        );
        if ($options) {
            $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);
        }
        if ($error_messages) {
            $this->error_messages = array_merge($this->error_messages, $error_messages);
        }
        if ($initialize) {
            $this->initialize();
        }
    }

    protected function initialize() {
        switch ($this->get_server_var('REQUEST_METHOD')) {
            case 'OPTIONS':
            case 'HEAD':
                $this->head();
                break;
            case 'GET':
                $this->get();
                break;
            case 'PATCH':
            case 'PUT':
            case 'POST':
                $this->post();
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $this->delete();
                break;
            default:
                $this->header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
        }
    }



    protected function set_file_delete_properties($file) {
        $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
            .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
            .'file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
        $file->delete_type = $this->options['delete_type'];
        if ($file->delete_type !== 'DELETE') {
            $file->delete_url .= '&_method=DELETE';
        }
        if ($this->options['access_control_allow_credentials']) {
            $file->delete_with_credentials = true;
        }
    }



    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        // Handle form data, e.g. $_REQUEST['description'][$index]
    }


    public function post($print_response = true) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
            return $this->delete($print_response);
        }
        ............

    }

    public function delete($print_response = true) {
        $file_name = $this->get_file_name_param();
        $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file_name);
        $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
        if ($success) {
           // $this->delete_img($file_name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if (!empty($version)) {
                    $file = $this->get_upload_path($file_name, $version);
                    if (is_file($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->generate_response(array('success' => $success), $print_response);
    }


    function delete_img($delimg)  
    {  
            $delete_from_db = $this->query("DELETE FROM `file_upload_multiple_images` WHERE `images` = '$delimg'") or die(mysql_error());  
            return $delete_from_db;  
    }
```

I'm unable to call this delete function to delete images from database as well as folders.
I want something to call a function of onclick of close icon.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use call back function to make it work.

The callback function is the function that will handle the data received from the server via the event fileuploaddone. Thus, you will have such code :

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', callbackfunc); 

// Your callback function
function callbackfunc(e, data) { 
    /* your code, like : if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message); */ 
}
```

But you can shorten it via an anonymous function :

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
             /* your code, like : if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message); */
 })
```

For deletion, the callback can be bound with event fileuploaddestroy (see this page : [BlueImp options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)).

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: actually I want to call the delete function of UploadHandler class as jquery file upload plugin already have. but they do it in different way.

Comment: will please open js file and in header list of function is address. you can call it when you need for specific event.